# UICollectionView Cells not shown if UITabBarController is on second tab Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a weird issue with UICollectionView and UITabBarController. Inside the UITabBarController i have references to two different ViewControllers. If i put View Controller that has UICollectionView as a first page of UITabBarController then my list with cells (UICollectionView) is loading normally like this:

[image: Normal loading]

But if i put it as a second View Controller when i open the tab it is like UIImageView and UILabel are disappearing from the cells:
[image: Loading on second tab]

I have checked collectionView method that is getting the cells and there is always data printed for the Label and Image. Here is a  code of the methods for DataSource and Delagate

```
   // tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AdsCollectionViewCell

    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // make cell more visible in our
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width - 22;
    return CGSize(width: width/2, height: width/2);
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}
```

Is there someone that had problem like this? How can it be solved?

Comment: have you tried reloading when selecting grid tab?...try reloading in viewwillappear...

Comment: i tried to put collectionView.reloadData() on viewwillapper method but still it is the same.

Comment: the interesting thing is that on iPhone 4s few of cells are loading normally but the others are not. On iPhone 6 and 5 no cell is loading when the UICollection is on second view.